# Creating association between entity to-many JPA

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, jpa, relational-database

I want to make association to some many-to-many relation entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private String userId;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<UserGroups> userGroups;
```

```
@Table(name = "groups")
@Data
public class Group {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "group_id")
    private String groupId;

    private String category;

    private String name;

    private String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "group")
    private List<UserGroups> userGroups;

    public void addUser(User user){
        UserGroup newUserGroup = new UserGroup();
        newUserGroup.setName(user.getName())
        userGroups.add(newUserGroup);
        user.getUserGroups().add(newUserGroup)
     }
```

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "user_groups")
public class UserGroups {

    @EmbeddedId
    UserGroupsCompositeKey id;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("userId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private Users user;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("featureId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "group_id")
    private Group group;
    private Date created;
```

I trying to add POST method to service where I should get group_id from endpoint url and assosiate user_id in request body. My Service method looks like this.

```
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<String> createUsersGroup(String groupId,
        String userId) {
            Optional<Group> group = groupRepository.findById(groupId).get();
            Optional<User> user = userRepository.findById(userId).get();
            group.addUser(user);

            return ResponseEntity.ok(userId);
        };
    }
```

Is there some more proper way to do this or when I will add more users in request body I will have to pull out every user from the database and add it like that ?